Tailwind border radius issue in table (React Framework)
I am new to tailwind framework with react and need assistance in this issue. I am trying to achieve the border-radius in tailwind of the table like in the image shown below

I am trying to achieve this by using the following code
 <table className='w-full border border-seperate border-spacing-2 rounded-sm'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className='border border-slate-600 rounded-md' >No</th>
              <th className='border border-slate-600 rounded-md' >Title</th>
              <th className='border border-slate-600 rounded-md max-md:hidden' >Author</th>
              <th className='border border-slate-600 rounded-md max-md:hidden' >Publish Year</th>
              <th className='border border-slate-600 rounded-md' >Operations</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {  books.map((book, index)=> (
              <tr key={book._id} className='h-8'>
                <td className='border border-solid border-slate-700 rounded-md text-center'>
                  {index + 1}
                </td>
                <td className='border border-slate-700 rounded-md text-center'>
                  {book.title};
                </td>
                <td className='border border-slate-700 rounded-md text-center max-md:hidden'>
                  {book.author}
                </td>
                <td className='border border-slate-700 rounded-md text-center max-md:hidden'>
                    { book.publishYear }
                </td>
                <td className='flex justify-center border border-slate-700 rounded-md'>
                  <Link to={`/books/details/${book._id}`}>
                    <BsInfoCircle className='text-2xl text-green-800' />
                  </Link>
                  <Link to={`/books/edit/${book._id}`}>
                    <AiOutlineEdit className='text-2xl text-yellow-800' />
                  </Link>
                  <Link to={`/books/delete/${book._id}`}>
                    <MdOutlineAddBox className='text-2xl text-red-800' />
                  </Link>
                </td>

              </tr>
              
            ))         
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
          
      )}


    </div>


What is the issue with the classes
And here is the image what I am getting


You misspelled border-seperate. You want border-separate.
See docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-collapse#separate
See playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/4S8QWyw2TS
